# signalr notifications based on nonweb originating events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Our system has two servers (S1) one is running processesing and data storage (basically DB) and the other one is a webserver (WS).

There are two types of even that can happen in the system:

1. User A pings User B. In this case we check if user B is logged in and we push a notification to User B client throw SignalR. It works.
2. Services constantly running on S1 and generating new data that concenrs multiple users. My goal is as soon as a new data important for user A is generated I immediately want to dispatch a signalR notification to user A client provided he/she is logged in.

This part 2 is not quite clear for me how to design. My thought right now is to start an indefinite process on webserves that monitors our DataBase and checks if new records are generated fpr this user and then push a SignalR message.

That would be fine, but now we have 10k users logged in and I don't think the right decision would be run 10k threads monitoring activities.

Basically, my question is what would a proper way do design signalR based notification mechanism that is based on events that are not originated on our webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a service bus or mq, for example this Free MQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/

You can proxy the messages direcly to the Clients using this proxy library (I'm the author).

Doc's here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Demo https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up a sql dependency that triggers a message to your signalr clients,

http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

This link is the one that I based my code on.

couple of things to watch for, the setup of the table. You cannot use 3 part table names

```
"SELECT [CMRID], 
   [SolutionID], 
   [CreateDT], 
   [ModifyDT] 
**FROM [dbo].[Case]** 
WHERE [ModifyDT] > " + LastExecutionDateTime;
```

Also, and this is very important, you MUST reset the event handler every time the dependency triggers, if not it will work the first time and then stop working.

I hope this helps you.